# Is there a way to access BIM360 project, C4R history?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am wondering if there is a way to access C4R history like who did the force relinquish and at when? Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what do you mean by c4r history in this context